# Unexpected text alignment behaviour when using a SwatchLegend with Inset

Tags: graphics, legending, inset

If I create a legend panel with a label which includes the new line escape character `"\n"`, e.g.

```
leg = SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, 
{"red", "green", 
   "long\nverbose\ncolour"}, 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Thick] &),
  LegendMargins -> 5]
```

[image]

All of the text is aligned to the left, however, when The object is included in another graphic using `Epilog->Inset[..]`The alignment of the label containing "\n" is now raggedly centred.

```
tri = Graphics[{Thick, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {100, 0}, {0.5*100, (Sqrt[3]/2)*100}, {0, 0}}]}];

Show[tri, Epilog -> Inset[leg, Scaled[{0.84, 0.74}]]]


Plot[2 Sin[x] - x, {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> Inset[leg, Scaled[{0.8, 0.74}]]]
```

[image]

I've tried using `Alignment->Left` to no avail. While the `SwatchLegend` contains graphic elements it is not a `Graphics` object. Clearly something changes when it is placed with `Inset`.

Any suggestions on why this is happening? Is there a better way to convert it to a graphic before embedding it in `Epilog`?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the option `Alignment -> Left` to `Inset` fixes the issue:

```
Row[{Show[tri, Epilog ->
   Inset[leg, Scaled[{0.84, 0.74}], Alignment -> Left], ImageSize -> 400],
  Plot[2 Sin[x] - x, {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> Inset[leg, Scaled[{0.8, 0.74}], Alignment -> Left],  ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]